# Ssis lookup input column shows as DT_WSTR inspite of varchar Cast when using OLEDB provider for Oracle

Tags: oracle, ssis, lookup

I've an OLEDB source which gets data from a Sql Server source. One of its columns gets casted as varchar(50).
I need to do a lookup on the above source using an Oracle source.

I'm using an SSIS Lookup which uses an OLEDB provider for Oracle to connect to the Oracle source. 
In the lookup connection tab, my query has Cast(column as varchar(50)) but when I go to the columns tab, this column shows as DT_WSTR when I hover over it.

This is causing my lookup join to fail since the oledb source output column is DT_STR whereas the lookup available input column is a DT_WSTR.

Any ideas why the lookup would behave like that?

Comment: Did you have the `CAST` to `varchar()` in your query originally or you added it later? Because SSIS does not automatically update the package with the new data type specified in your query.

Comment: It was originally added. I know that SSIS makes you manually change output datatype if u change it later. I even tried creating a new lookup and it did the same weird thing.

Comment: One way around it is to instead cast the column in your `Look Up` query to match `DT_WSTR`.

Comment: Well that's one of my plans. But unless I find out why it's doing it, I'm a bit worried if I'm solving the right problem. The background is that this same code was working till now for another oracle source. I tried a new oracle source now which matches wrt the column datatype and all, but still face this.